# Convergence in law of maximum likelihood estimator and the method of moments estimator of the uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

So I have these random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n $ iid. and a uniform distribution: $f_X(x)=1/\theta*\textbf{1}_{0\leq x\leq\theta} $. The maximum likelihood estimator is $\tilde{\theta}_n=max\{ X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ and the method of moments estimator $\hat{\theta}_n=2/n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. These are estimators for $\theta$. Now I need to find the asymptomatic laws of these two: $$ \sqrt n (\tilde{\theta}_n-\theta)$$
and
$$n(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)$$

For the first one I want to use the central limit theorem somehow but the estimator is not a sum and I'm a bit lost. I also cannot see how I can use Slutsky, the delta method or the continuous application theorems.

For the second I have:
$$n(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)=2(\sum X_i-\theta n/2)=2\sum (X_i-\theta/2)$$

and $(X_i-\theta/2)$ is a $Unif[-\theta/2,\theta/2]$ but the dostribution associated to this sum (that I find online) is a distribution that we haven't seen in class so I am not so sure.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Edit: additional question. Also how can I show that the second one ($\hat{\theta}_n$) is not a sufficient statistic? It is quite obvious how to show that the first one IS.

Comment: Usually the scaling "$n$" is used for the MLE and "$\sqrt n$" is used for method of moment estimator. This makes the corresponding limiting distributions non-degenerate. Of course, you can say $\sqrt n(\tilde\theta_n-\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\cdot n(\tilde\theta_n-\theta)$ and use Slutsky's theorem.